# Is it possible to directly rename pandas dataframe's columns stored in hdf5 file?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, hdf5

I have a very large pandas dataframe stored in hdf5 file, and I need to rename the columns of the dataframe.

The straightforward way is to read the dataframe in chunks using HDFStore.select, rename the columns and store the chunks to another hdf5 file.

But I think this is a stupid and inefficient way. Is there a way to directly rename the columns in hdf5 file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by changing the meta-data. BIG WARNING. This may corrupt your file, so you are at your own risk.

Create a store. Must be a table format. I didn't use `data_columns` here, but the change is only slight to rename those.

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3),columns=list('abc'))

In [2]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',format='table')
In [24]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',format='table')

In [25]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df')
Out[25]: 
          a         b         c
0  1.366298  0.844646 -0.470735
1 -1.438387 -1.288432  0.250763
2 -1.290225 -0.390315 -0.138440
3  2.343019  0.632340 -0.539334
4 -1.184943  0.566479  1.977939
5 -1.530772  0.757110 -0.013930
6 -0.300345 -0.951563 -1.013957
7 -0.073975 -0.256521  1.024525
8 -0.179189 -1.767918  0.591720
9  0.641028  0.205522  1.947618
```

Get a handle to the table itself

```
In [26]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
```

You need to change meta-data in 2 places. First here at the top-level

```
In [28]: store.get_storer('df').attrs['non_index_axes']
Out[28]: [(1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])]

In [29]: store.get_storer('df').attrs.non_index_axes = [(1, ['new','b','c'])]
```

Then here

```
In [31]: store.get_storer('df').table.attrs
Out[31]: 
/df/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 12 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'TABLE',
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'values_block_0',
    NROWS := 10,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    index_kind := 'integer',
    values_block_0_dtype := 'float64',
    values_block_0_kind := ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    values_block_0_meta := None]

In [33]: store.get_storer('df').table.attrs.values_block_0_kind = ['new','b','c']
```

Close the store to save

```
In [34]: store.close()

In [35]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df')
Out[35]: 
        new         b         c
0  1.366298  0.844646 -0.470735
1 -1.438387 -1.288432  0.250763
2 -1.290225 -0.390315 -0.138440
3  2.343019  0.632340 -0.539334
4 -1.184943  0.566479  1.977939
5 -1.530772  0.757110 -0.013930
6 -0.300345 -0.951563 -1.013957
7 -0.073975 -0.256521  1.024525
8 -0.179189 -1.767918  0.591720
9  0.641028  0.205522  1.947618
```

Comment: can this be a feature request for Pandas?

Comment: Sure. Seems reasonable. Pls post an issue if you would.