# HDF5: Is there a way to rename the column names in an existing HDF5 table?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdfstore

I used Pandas to create a large, indexed HDF5 table. I'd like to rename 2 of the columns out of the 12 columns in my table. I would prefer not to rebuild/reindex the table.

Can this be done without copying all the data (140GB)? I'm hoping there are just a couple pieces of metadata in the file that could be easily swapped out with the right command.

This came up for me because I have a few "non-natural" column names with spaces in them, and didn't realize this was an issue until trying to run a select statement.

Comment: AFAIK there is no yet a "fair" way to do that, but you can use [this Jeff's hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32082953/5741205)

Comment: Good idea -- doesn't seem to work for me though, perhaps because I have an indexed table. I modified all the "attrs" metadata I could find according to Jeff's hack -- including some extra fields that appeared for me -- but "select" still doesn't recognize the new column name. When I do s.get_storer('all').table.colindexes, I see that the columns are still named with the old names.

Comment: yeah, with indexed columns, you have more "homework"... Check `store.get_storer('all')` for the columns you want to rename and try to rename them. Also take a look at the [PyTables's _f_rename() method](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/tutorials.html)

Comment: So yeah, I did all that but I can't find the right spot. Looking in store.get_storer('all') makes it look like I renamed all the columns. However, store.get_storer('all').table yields both a "tables.description.Description" object and a "tables.table._ColIndexes" object that have the old names (even after closing/opening the store). I'm not sure where these Table internal things are getting the column names, but it's not in any obvious (to me) place accessible via store.get_storer('all').table.attrs -- all this metadata (including attributes such as "COL NAME_dtype" has my new column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid currently there is no way to rename indexed (belonging to `data_columns`) column as this would require making changes in `storer.table.colindexes` and in `storer.table.description` objects and both of them are of the specific types:

```
In [29]: store.get_storer('df').table
Out[29]:
/df/table (Table(10,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "a": Int32Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=1),
  "b": Int32Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "c": Int32Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=3)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (3276,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "a": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "c": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "b": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}

In [30]: type(store.get_storer('df').table.colindexes)
Out[30]: tables.table._ColIndexes

In [31]: type(store.get_storer('df').table.description)
Out[31]: tables.description.Description
```

If you try to google for a PyTables solution you will find this question, but there was/is no answer which would allow you to rename columns.

So you may want to recreate your HDF5 file(s)

Comment: Yes, I've come to the same conclusion. I'd like to know if this is a limitation of PyTables or of HDF5 though. But for now it seems like the only solution is to recreate the file.